# Azure Resource Manager - Move from one subscription to another subscription

Tags: azure

I have a Azure resource manager that is managing a VM and AD resources. I want to move or copy the resource manager from my Azure Subscription to my Company's Azure subscription. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the Portal, PowerShell and REST but not all resources can be moved, ex: VPN Gateways, Virtual Machine ScaleSet, Virtual Networks created in classic mode

You can check how to move or copy the resources in different ways from this link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/

Comment: The desired destination subscription is not showing in target subscription dropdown list to initiate the move. The target is a customer's subscription with whom we have a reseller relationship. I want to move a storage resource from our subscription to their subscription via azure due to the size of the resource. Any idea what to do?